# PL/SQL spool Oracle tables to one csv file

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

Is it possible to spool multiple Oracle tables to one csv file (in different wooksheets)?
I so, how?

Thanks :)

Comment: CSV file has only one worksheet

Comment: CSV file has no worksheets - it's a simple plain-text file.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to spool one table to one CSV, using SQL*Plus. As noted, you need a separate CSV for each table/query - that's how CSV's and Excel work.

This example spools some of the tables from the Oracle `HR.Employees` sample table. Here's what the table looks like:

```
SQL> desc hr.employees
 Name            Null?    Type
 --------------- -------- -------------
 EMPLOYEE_ID     NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 FIRST_NAME               VARCHAR2(20)
 LAST_NAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 EMAIL           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 PHONE_NUMBER             VARCHAR2(20)
 HIRE_DATE       NOT NULL DATE
 JOB_ID          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 SALARY                   NUMBER(8,2)
 COMMISSION_PCT           NUMBER(2,2)
 MANAGER_ID               NUMBER(6)
 DEPARTMENT_ID            NUMBER(4)
```

Here's a SQL script that spools some of the `HR` columns. It includes numeric, char and date values:

```
-- SpoolEmployeesToCSV.sql
SET ECHO OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 2000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL c:\Business\HREmployees.csv

SELECT
  TO_CHAR(Employee_ID) || ',' ||
  '"' || REPLACE(First_Name, '"', '""') || '"' ||
  ',"' || REPLACE(Last_Name, '"', '""') || '",' ||
  ',' || TO_CHAR(Hire_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ||
  ',' || TO_CHAR(Salary)
FROM HR.Employees

SPOOL OFF
```

This script happens to be named `SpoolEmployeesToCSV.sql`. To call it from SQL*Plus just go like this:

```
SQL>@SpoolEmployeesToCSV.sql
```

That's all. You may need to experiment with different date and number formats, but the main thing about spooling to a file is all of the `SET` commands at the top of the script, plus the fact that *all* of the commands are in the script - if you try to execute them directly from the SQL*Plus command line they'll end up in the spooled output.

[Edit] One more thing - the `SET LINESIZE 2000`. You have to set the value larger than your expected line size. It can be a lot larger because the `SET TRIMSPOOL ON` will chop each line down to size.

Comment: I needed to know how to remove extra linebreaks and how to trim the lines. This answer gave me what I needed; I found what I needed to learn elsewhere, but the problem was I didn't even know what to search for :)